# RegEx special char "|" escaping in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, special-characters

I am trying to split a string like: abc|aa||
When I use the regular string.split I am required to provide a regular expression.
I tried to do the following :
    string.split("|")
    string.split("\|")
    string.split("/|")
    string.split("\Q|\E")

Non of them work.....

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Try `string.split("\\|")`

Comment: `"abc|aa||".split("\Q|\E")` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you tried, but

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a= "abc|aa||";
    String split = Pattern.quote("|");
    System.out.println(split);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.split(split)));
}
```

prints out

```
\Q|\E
[abc, aa]
```

effectively splitting on `|`. The `\Q ... \E` is a regex quote. Anything inside it will be matched as a literal pattern.

---

```
string.split("\|"); // won't work because \| is not a valid escape sequence
string.split("/|"); // will compile, but split on / and empty space, so between each character
string.split("|");  // will compile, but split on empty space, so between each character

// true alternative to quoted solution above
 string.split("\\|") // escape the second \ which will resolve as an escaped | in the regex pattern
```

Comment: Thanks!
Is there a way in which I will also get the empty spaces?
So for the above String I will get: [abc,aa,]?

Comment: Another thing,
When I try the line:
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.split("\Q|\E")));
I get an error.... Why is that?

Comment: @ron You probably haven't imported the `Arrays` class. To get the space, i think there is an overloaded `split` method that can do that for you. I can't check right now. LEt me get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

using a double backslash is required because the backslash is also a special character. So you need to escape the escape character. i.e.  \
\|

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a special character hence you need to escape it using slashes. Try using

`string.split("\\|")`

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a special character for the regular expression, thus it must be escaped e.g. `\|`

The backslash `\` is a special character in Java, thus it must also be escaped

As a result, must do the following to achieve the desired effect.

```
string.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the following patterns split it all right: `"\\Q|\\E"` `"\\|"` `"[|]"` of course the latter two are preferrable